# Can I abort DB operation / transaction in TypeORM using AbortSignal?

Tags: node.js, typeorm, abort

Is there a built-in TypeORM feature for aborting DB operation using AbortSignal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no such feature, I opened an issue ([`TypeORM#8552`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8552)) in GitHub requesting this feature.